# Calling CreateProcess from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, createprocess

I'm trying to call [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from PowerShell. The API call indicates that it succeeded, but no new application or process is visible in Task Manager.

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    public IntPtr hProcess;
    public IntPtr hThread;
    public uint dwProcessId;
    public uint dwThreadId;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct STARTUPINFO
{
    public uint cb;
    public string lpReserved;
    public string lpDesktop;
    public string lpTitle;
    public uint dwX;
    public uint dwY;
    public uint dwXSize;
    public uint dwYSize;
    public uint dwXCountChars;
    public uint dwYCountChars;
    public uint dwFillAttribute;
    public STARTF dwFlags;
    public ShowWindow wShowWindow;
    public short cbReserved2;
    public IntPtr lpReserved2;
    public IntPtr hStdInput;
    public IntPtr hStdOutput;
    public IntPtr hStdError;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public int length;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public bool bInheritHandle;
}

[Flags]
public enum CreationFlags : int
{
    NONE = 0,
    DEBUG_PROCESS = 0x00000001,
    DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS = 0x00000002,
    CREATE_SUSPENDED = 0x00000004,
    DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010,
    CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200,
    CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400,
    CREATE_SEPARATE_WOW_VDM = 0x00000800,
    CREATE_SHARED_WOW_VDM = 0x00001000,
    CREATE_PROTECTED_PROCESS = 0x00040000,
    EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT = 0x00080000,
    CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB = 0x01000000,
    CREATE_PRESERVE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL = 0x02000000,
    CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE = 0x04000000,
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000,
}

[Flags]
public enum STARTF : uint
{
    STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x00000001,
    STARTF_USESIZE = 0x00000002,
    STARTF_USEPOSITION = 0x00000004,
    STARTF_USECOUNTCHARS = 0x00000008,
    STARTF_USEFILLATTRIBUTE = 0x00000010,
    STARTF_RUNFULLSCREEN = 0x00000020,  // ignored for non-x86 platforms
    STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK = 0x00000040,
    STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK = 0x00000080,
    STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x00000100,
}

public enum ShowWindow : short
{
    SW_HIDE = 0,
    SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1,
    SW_NORMAL = 1,
    SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2,
    SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3,
    SW_MAXIMIZE = 3,
    SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4,
    SW_SHOW = 5,
    SW_MINIMIZE = 6,
    SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7,
    SW_SHOWNA = 8,
    SW_RESTORE = 9,
    SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10,
    SW_FORCEMINIMIZE = 11,
    SW_MAX = 11
}

public static class Kernel32
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern bool CreateProcess(
        string lpApplicationName, 
        string lpCommandLine, 
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes, 
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
        bool bInheritHandles, 
        CreationFlags dwCreationFlags, 
        IntPtr lpEnvironment,
        string lpCurrentDirectory, 
        ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, 
        out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

}
"@


$si = New-Object STARTUPINFO
$pi = New-Object PROCESS_INFORMATION

$si.cb = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($si)
$si.wShowWindow = [ShowWindow]::SW_SHOW

$pSec = New-Object SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
$tSec = New-Object SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
$pSec.Length = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($pSec)
$tSec.Length = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($tSec)

[Kernel32]::CreateProcess("c:\windows\notepad.exe", $null, [ref] $pSec, [ref] $tSec, $false, [CreationFlags]::NONE, [IntPtr]::Zero, $null, [ref] $si, [ref] $pi)

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetLastWin32Error()

$pi
```

Comment: Have you tested the p\invoke  in a C# solution?

Comment: I quickly made a translation in c# and it works "as is".

Comment: Well that's encouraging, but I'd still like to get it working in PowerShell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a real CurrentDirectory instead of `$null`:

```
[Kernel32]::CreateProcess("c:\windows\notepad.exe", $null, [ref] $pSec, [ref] $tSec, $false, [CreationFlags]::NONE, [IntPtr]::Zero, "c:", [ref] $si, [ref] $pi)
```

Comment: This was the answer for me as well.  C# PInvoke is fine with `null` but PowerShell wants an actual directory.  In my case `GetLastWin32Error()` was returning **123** which is `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`.

Comment: I changed it to `[Kernel32]::CreateProcess("c:\windows\system32\alg.exe", "c:\windows\system32", [ref] $pSec, [ref] $tSec, $false, [CreationFlags]::NONE, [IntPtr]::Zero, $null, [ref] $si, [ref] $pi)` and I am getting an error 203 - ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND, "The system could not find the environment option that was entered."